# Unclear on what will happen during next Windows 10 major OS update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I installed Windows 10 Pro from scratch in September 2017. I built USB installer with the latest OS version at the time.

My Advanced options for updates are as follows:

Branch readiness: Semi-Annual Channel

Feature update: Defer for 365 days

Quality update: Defer for 30 days

Basically I am REALLY not into being a beta-tester for Microsoft.

Currently I am at Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.611)

I am unclear on when the major OS update will occur to me and what will happen when it does (never had one happen yet).

As it is now October 2018 - does it mean I will be upgraded to the new OS version any time now whether I want it or not?

What version will I be upgraded to? 1803 or 1809?

How does upgrade really happen? Will I be given an opportunity to make a full OS backup before? Or will Windows just quietly download everything required and start it whenever it feels like?

Comment: While I submitted an answer to this question, you might consider reducing the number of questions you have asked, or ask fewer questions worded in such a way you still get the answers you are looking for looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically I am REALLY not into being a beta-tester for Microsoft.

`Semi-Annual Channel` is considered the most stable release channel.  `Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)` is considered to be stable but is targeted to known compatible configurations.  In other words `Semi-Annual Channel` is released to everyone, and `Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)` is only pushed to systems that are known to be compatible with it.

[image]

> I am unclear on when the major OS update will occur to me and what will happen when it does (never had one happen yet).

Your system would be updated to the current `Semi-Annual Channel` build which is currently, as of October 2018, is Windows 10 Version 1803.

[image]

[image]

> As it is now October 2018 - does it mean I will be upgraded to the new OS version any time now whether I want it or not?

Eventually, you would be forced to install the next build, contained within the `Semi-Annual Channel` branch.  You have Windows 10 configured to wait 365 days, until the next feature update, within the `Semi-Annual Channel` branch will be installed.  **When the update will be installed exactly on your system cannot be determined with the information you have provided.**  You really should be running 1803 at this point anyways.

> All releases of Windows 10 have 18 months of servicing for all
>   editions--these updates provide security and feature updates for the
>   release. Customers running Enterprise and Education editions have an
>   additional 12 months of servicing for specific Windows 10 releases,
>   for a total of 30 months from initial release.

Source: [Semi-Annual Channel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview#semi-annual-channel)

> What version will I be upgraded to? 1803 or 1809?

You would be upgraded to which version is in the `Semi-Annual Channel` branch at the time of the upgrade.

> How does upgrade really happen?

The feature update would be downloaded in the background, and since you are running 1709, the majority of the installation would happen in the background.  At some point, you would be prompted to perform a restart to finish the installation of the feature update.

> Will I be given an opportunity to make a full OS backup before?

You make a habit of making routine system backups.

> Will Windows just quietly download everything required and start it whenever it feels like?

Yes;  Feature updates are required since you are running Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. As far as security updates go: am I correct in assuming that all currently supported Windows 10 versions are equally secure? That is they all receive security patches for all discovered vulnerabilities?

Comment: @JoeSchmoe, the simple answer is "yes."  However, to expand upon what Ramhound said earlier, we are always glad to help but your original post really is far too broad.  While it is beneficial to the community, you essentially asked four or five separate (although related) questions.  When you have some time to spare, peruse through the articles at How-To Geek or the Ten Forums domains.  They provide a comprehensive overview of the Windows 10 update processes.

Comment: @JoeSchmoe - Are all versions of Windows 10, equally secure, significant improvements to security have been made to various versions of Windows 10.  So I wouldn't say, they are all equally secure, I would say they are all supported and any major security vulnerability will be fixed.